# Lifetime of variable after if block

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
>>> if True:
...     a = 4
... 
>>> print a
4
```

Why variable **a** is still alive after **if** block? Shouldn't it be destroyed when block **if** ends?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python variables have scope inside a `function`, `class` or `module`. Variables initialised in `if` statements, `while` statements and `for` statements are available outside the if/while/for statement for use

This is different to many other languages where accessing the variable would throw an exception because of it being out of scope

Just to note, if the if/while/for statement is false and does not execute, `a` for example would not be initialised and it would throw an error like so:

```
>>> if False:
...     a = 5
... 
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: "Most other languages" would treat a variable inside an if-block as out of scope??

Comment: As in if you declare and initialise a variable in an if block, it would have scope only within that if block.

Comment: Here is a Link to the relevant section of the Python documentation: [Naming and Binding](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Comment: Could you give some examples of languages where this is the case? I thought that Python's behaviour was "usual"!

Comment: C++ or C99 if you do `for (int x = 0; x< 0; x++)` and Java as well. But of course, then the variable is declared in the loop itself.

Comment: C/C++ and Java definitely come to mind. I thought PHP was like that too but just tried an example like above and worked fine.

Comment: @BenRuijl in a for loop is a special case (it's not an **if block**), but you are right this behaviour is different from python.